# Google's WorkStealingDequeue use memory_order_seq_cst as full memory barrier. Is it valid?

Tags: c++, concurrency, atomic, memory-barriers

I am studying Google's filament job system. Currently, I am studying the WorkStealingDequeue they implemented. You can look at the full source code [here](https://github.com/google/filament/blob/master/libs/utils/include/utils/WorkStealingDequeue.h) . This data structure is based on this [work](https://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/PDF/work-stealing-dequeue.pdf). In their implementation of pop and steal, they use memory_order_seq_cst as a full memory barrier.

```
template <typename TYPE, size_t COUNT>
TYPE WorkStealingDequeue<TYPE, COUNT>::pop() noexcept {
    // mBottom is only written in push(), which cannot be concurrent with pop(),
    // however, it is read in steal(), so we need basic atomicity.
    //   i.e.: bottom = mBottom--;
    int32_t bottom = mBottom.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_relaxed) - 1;

    // we need a full memory barrier here; mBottom must be written and visible to
    // other threads before we read mTop.
    int32_t top = mTop.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst);

    if (top < bottom) {
        // Queue isn't empty and it's not the last item, just return it.
        return getItemAt(bottom);
    }

    TYPE item{};
    if (top == bottom) {
        // We took the last item in the queue
        item = getItemAt(bottom);

        // Items can be added only in push() which isn't concurrent to us, however we could
        // be racing with a steal() -- pretend to steal from ourselves to resolve this
        // potential conflict.
        if (mTop.compare_exchange_strong(top, top + 1,
                std::memory_order_seq_cst,
                std::memory_order_relaxed)) {
            // success: mTop was equal to top, mTop now equals top+1
            // We successfully poped an item, adjust top to make the queue canonically empty.
            top++;
        } else {
            // failure: mTop was not equal to top, which means the item was stolen under our feet.
            // top now equals to mTop. Simply discard the item we just poped.
            // The queue is now empty.
            item = TYPE();
        }
    }

    // no concurrent writes to mBottom possible
    mBottom.store(top, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    return item;
}

template <typename TYPE, size_t COUNT>
TYPE WorkStealingDequeue<TYPE, COUNT>::steal() noexcept {
    do {
        // mTop must be read before mBottom
        int32_t top = mTop.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst);

        // mBottom is written concurrently to the read below in pop() or push(), so
        // we need basic atomicity. Also makes sure that writes made in push()
        // (prior to mBottom update) are visible.
        int32_t bottom = mBottom.load(std::memory_order_acquire);

        if (top >= bottom) {
            // queue is empty
            return TYPE();
        }

        // The queue isn't empty
        TYPE item(getItemAt(top));
        if (mTop.compare_exchange_strong(top, top + 1,
                std::memory_order_seq_cst,
                std::memory_order_relaxed)) {
            // success: we stole a job, just return it.
            return item;
        }
        // failure: the item we just tried to steal was pop()'ed under our feet,
        // simply discard it; nothing to do.
    } while (true);
}
```

For the implementation to be correct, It is required that mBottom to be fetched before mTop in pop() and mTop to be fetched before mBottom in steal(). If we think memory_order_seq_cst as a full memory barrier like most implementation do, then the above code is correct. But from what I understand, C++11 doesn't say anything about memory_order_seq_cst as full memory barrier. From what I understand to ensure the correct ordering then the mBottom fetch_sub operation must be at least std::memory_order_acq_rel. Is my analysis correct?

And then is memory_order_seq_cst on mTop necessary? memory_order_seq_cst force all operation on mTop to be on a single total order(STO). But in this case, the only one that participate in the STO is mTop. I believe we already have modification order guarantee which stated that every threads must agree on the modification order of every variable relative to itself. Is memory_order_acq_rel in the compare_exchange_strong operation enough?

Comment: What is a "full memory barrier"?

Comment: All operation before memory_order_seq_cst must be executed before the synchronization operation. Operation with memory_order_seq_cst must be executed before all operation after it. It is a barrier that prevents reordering on both direction. I am not sure whether it is the correct term.

Comment: Yes, all operations potentially measurable by other threads. Like an ack-rel barrier.

Comment: There's another paper that provides an implementation of the Lev-Chase algorithm in terms of C11 atomics that aren't sequentially consistent everywhere. The paper provides a proof of correctness (which I don't pretend to follow): https://fzn.fr/readings/ppopp13.pdf. They imply sequential consistency *is* indeed required in some those places in steal() and pop() (not in fetch_sub: that should be doable with a relaxed read, a subtraction and a relaxed write). Interestingly, I believe they're proved-to-be-correct algorithm is incorrect in having take() store b+1 to bottom rather than t+1.

Comment: The problem mentioned by Anthony Williams should be a practical non-issue. `getItemAt(top)` might speculatively read a torn value there, which is technically a "race" and therefore technically UB, but there's no way either compilers or hardware will mess up there. This standard proposal even tries to rectify this defect in the standard by explicitly allowing tearable reads: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0690r1.html and it explicitly mentions this Lev-Chase algorithm as a possible application of such a feature.

Answer (score 3):

This code has a data race in `steal`, and therefore undefined behaviour, regardless of the memory orderings.

There is nothing preventing the stealing thread calling `getItemAt(top)` to read the value at a given index, while the worker thread that owns the queue calls `push` enough times to wrap around the buffer and overwrite the entry, or calls `pop` enough times to empty the queue and then calls `push` to overwrite that entry.

e.g. `mTop` is 0, `mBottom` is 1 => queue has one element.

Stealing thread reads `mTop` and `mBottom`. `top<bottom`, so it gets to the call the `getItemAt(top)` and is suspended by the OS due to task switching.

Worker thread calls `pop`. It reads `mBottom` and sets `bottom` to 0. It then reads `top` (0). `0==0`, so we call `getItemAt(bottom)` to retrieve the item. It then increments `mTop` to 1, and sets `mBottom` to 1.

Worker thread then calls `push` and calls `setItemAt(mBottom)` to set the next element, which is now element 1.

The worker thread now repeats this `push`/`pop` dance `COUNT` times, so the queue never has more than one element, but each time incrementing `mTop` and `mBottom` so the active element is moved round the buffer until `mBottom & MASK` is again 0.

The worker thread calls `push` and thus `setItemAt(mBottom)`, which accesses element 0. The OS resumes the stealing thread, which also is accessing element 0 => read and write to the same location without ordering => data race and undefined behaviour.

This is only OK if `TYPE` is `std::atomic<T>` for some `T`.

Assuming that `COUNT` is large enough that in practice this never happens, then `push` write to `mBottom` with `memory_order_release`, and `steal` reads with `memory_order_acquire`. This means the the write to the relevant data item happens-before the read of the item in `steal`, so reading the item is OK. This is visible even with the `fetch_sub` in `pop` using `memory_order_relaxed` due to a concept called "release sequences".

The use of `memory_order_seq_cst` on the loads and successful compare-exchange of `mTop` forces the operations on `mTop` into a single global total order. However, the comment on the load of `mTop` in `pop` is wrong: the use of `memory_order_seq_cst` does not prevent the `mBottom.fetch_sub` call being reordered, as this is a `load` from `mTop`, and the `fetch_sub` call uses `memory_order_relaxed`. The `memory_order_seq_cst` on the `load` does not impose any ordering on non-`memory_order_seq_cst` writes from the same thread to other variables.

I am not sure at this time what the impact on this may be on the code.

Comment: Interesting, what If we remove the wrap around mechanism. Instead, we always reset the deque every frame and make an assertion that the job inside the queue in a frame will never be more than COUNT? I still wonder whether memory_order_seq_cst automatically translate to a full memory barrier. I found this statement a lot.

Comment: Okay, after thinking some more. I realize that this deque is used for a job system. So the wrap around might be mitigated by ensuring that the number of job for every frame per dequeue must not be greater than COUNT. This can be done by waiting for all job on this frame before pushing job for the next frame.

Comment: "*The memory_order_seq_cst on the load does not impose any ordering on non-memory_order_seq_cst writes from the same thread to other variables.*" Um, yes it does. That's the whole point of memory orders: to impose ordering between the atomic operation/barrier and previous operations in the same thread. It's not (just) about the atomic operation itself; it's about the relationship between that atomic operation and any prior operations on the thread. `relaxed` isn't some global opt-out of any ordering; later barriers can impose ordering on an object that itself doesn't impose ordering.

Comment: This is why a non-atomic operation can be made visible to other threads if it is followed by `memory_order_seq_cst` barrier. That is, if someone can see the value of an atomic which was set via `memory_order_seq_cst`, then they can also see the other operations issued before that barrier on the issuing thread.

Comment: Consider `x.store(42,memory_order_relaxed); y.load(memory_order_seq_cst);` The `memory_order_seq_cst` operation is a *load*. It does not impose an order on the prior *store* from the same thread. If it had said `y.store(99,memory_order_seq_cst)` then it *would* impose an ordering on the store. *Loads are not release operations*

Comment: @AnthonyWilliams Even if loads were (nop)write operations and had release semantics, since you can't know whether the (nop)write happened (as no different value was written), you (usually?) wouldn't be able to use that release semantics. "_If it had said y.store(99,memory_order_seq_cst) then_" ... it would be directly observable by other threads (unless y is 99 before).

Comment: I guess the issue is with `{{{ x.store(42,mo_relaxed); y.load(mo_seq_cst);  ||| y.store(42,mo_seq_cst); x.load(mo_relaxed); }}}` Can the load on y see 42 w/o the load on x seeing 42 also?

Comment: @AnthonyWilliams Is memory_order_seq_cst in mTop necessary? As you said memory_order_seq_cst forces global total order. But in this case the only variable that participate in the total order is mTop. Without global total order, we already have modification order guarantee. Every thread have to agree on a single modification order for every single variable. It seems like that is already enough.

Comment: @kevinyu Maybe the author expected more from seq_cst than what is really provided: seq_cst may be the most difficult to get (and not consume that everybody claims is difficult)

Comment: @kevinyu I think the `memory_order_seq_cst` operations are not doing what the author of the code intended. They order the operations on `mTop`, but that doesn't provide much benefit, as you say. I don't think the code is correct, but don't have time to do a full analysis just now. I did edit my answer to include more details, but somehow the changes got lost.

Comment: The race does not exist. The owner of the deque only calls push & pop, and not concurrently; see "Thread Scheduling for Multiprogrammed Multiprocessors" (the paper introducing it).

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis But steal can still be concurrent with push and pop. I think the case that Anthony mention can still happen between steal and push/pop.

Comment: Wouldn't this be more of a defect in the standard, though? As long as TYPE is plain old data, no hardware/compiler should mess this up, no? The stealer would simply get a garbage (e.g., partially written) value and throw it away and the attempted read shouldn't mess up the concurrent write. Does this really *need* to be UB?

Comment: Looks like I'm not the only one who thinks that (it is a defect in the standard): http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0690r1.html